# I'm struggling to iterate past the first character of a string in a for loop when ord() is being used

Tags: python, for-loop, ord

I am trying to make a Ceasar Cipher. Struggling to get the ord() then shift it and then chr() for the encryption. I can get the first character in 'abc' and get an output of 'b' but not the whole string 'bcd'.

I feel it has to do with the return or not meeting the condition of going through the whole range, but I don't know how to troubleshoot. Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

```
def cCipher(text,shift):
    #First identify whether text is a string or note.
    if type(text) != str:
        return "The input is not a string"

    #Get the ord() for each letter in string and shift
    else:
        for i in range(len(text)):
            code = chr(ord(text[i])+shift)
            return code


#This will be my test functions
print(cCipher('abc', 1))
```

Comment: `return` ends the function. The loop doens't repeat if you return inside the loop.

Comment: You need to accumulate all the codes in a result string. Then return the result at the end of the loop.

Comment: Caesar cipher also needs to wrap around at the end of the alphabet. You're not handling that.

Comment: Because you always `return code` on the first iteration

Comment: I should add too if I move the return outside of the for loop the output is 'd'. So still not going from 'abc' to 'bcd'.

Comment: I hope this is part of an assignment. As a general rule, never implement your own encryption primitives :)

Comment: @JohnMoody yeah, it's a coding exercise to learn for loops-- beginner here!

Answer (score 0):

You are terminating the function by calling `return code`.

Try this instead:

```
def cCipher(text,shift):
    #First identify whether text is a string or note.
    if type(text) != str:
        return "The input is not a string"

    #Get the ord() for each letter in string and shift
    else:
        code = ""
        for i in range(len(text)):
            code += chr(ord(text[i])+shift)
        return code


#This will be my test functions
print(cCipher('abc', 1))
```

Please note that there are other deficiencies in this code. The revised version I posted above fixes the issue you are experiencing but does not address any other issues.

Comment: Testing the input to see if it's a string and returning some arbitrary response is a bad idea. Let the exceptions do their thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Agreed. There are many issues with this code. I only addressed the issue that the OP asked about.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that bit in the OP's code. Thought it was something you added.

Comment: It's part of an assignment to help me learn how to code loops. returning a response is part of the criteria.